# swift metal HDR video цветопередача

Tags: ios, swift, color

я разрабатываю приложение в котором требуется загружать видео из галереи и обрабатывать в шейдере через Metal

все работает за исключением цветопередачи на видео которые были записаны с поддержкой HDR

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в зеленом квадрате верная цветопередача, слой ниже это рендер из Metal

я написал тестовый проект в котором можно воспроизвести проблему - https://github.com/easyproger/testHDRcolor

так же я нашел решение с получением текстуры через контекст, но при таком способе производительность падает в два раза по сравнению с CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

пример контекста:

```
context = CIContext(mtlDevice: device, options: [
      .workingFormat: CIFormat.RGBAh,
      .workingColorSpace: colorSpace
])
context.render(image, to: texture, commandBuffer: nil, bounds: image.extent, colorSpace: colorSpace)
```

пример через CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

```
func createTexture(fromPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat, planeIndex: Int) -> MTLTexture? {
    var mtlTexture: MTLTexture? = nil
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, planeIndex)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, planeIndex)
        
    var texture: CVMetalTexture? = nil
    let status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil, textureCache!, pixelBuffer, nil, pixelFormat, width, height, planeIndex, &texture)
    if status == kCVReturnSuccess {
        mtlTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture!)
    }
        
    return mtlTexture
}
```

я понимаю что проблема лежит в цветопередаче, но как ее решить не теряя производительность, не могу найти

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, пока не получится так как Вы хотите на iOS.

Metal поддерживает рендеринг с использованием формата [MTLPixelFormatBGR10_XR_sRGB](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat/mtlpixelformatbgr10_xr_srgb?language=objc), но на iOS пока не выходит за пределы цветового пространства P3

Как выглядит работа Metal с HDR:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для последнего шага необходим [wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478161-wantsextendeddynamicrangecontent), который доступен только на macOS.

Comment: ага я натыкался на это, но меня больше интересует восстановление цветов, они явно сильно блеклые чем должны быть, ведь контекст же как то восстанавливает цвета, да они не такие яркие как с эффектом HDR, но они явно ярче чем выходит у меня, то есть контекст применяет какие то корректировки цвета, вот я хочу их применить без падения производительности